# Navigation Bar Buttons disappearing

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a StoryBoard which contains a TabBarController, the buttons of which are each linked to ViewControllers which have been embedded in Navigation Controllers. There is a certain point in the app where I need to show a View which is not a part of this TabBarController and then back to the TabBarController. I am using a drawer to toggle between the two views (TabBar and the seperate ViewController). I am using this code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of the tableView of the drawer

```
case 0:
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil) 
    break;

case 1:
    var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! TabBarController
    var centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    appDelegate.centerContainer?.setCenterViewController(centerNav, withFullCloseAnimation: true, completion: nil)
    appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
    break
```

Case 2 makes the navigation bar button items on the Navigation Controllers in the TabBarController disappear. Why?